# SOAPUI Missing token in response

Tags: web-services, soapui

I have been walking through a course on SOAPUI relating to the following `conversion Rate API` that is mentioned in https://www.soapui.org/docs/data-driven-tests/using-files.html

When setting up a test case to convert from `EUR` to `USD` and adding an assertion of `1.318` it returns failed -- `Missing token[1.318] in response`.

The XML response is as follows, however i can not see why it is failing and there is no further information. The only indication is that for some reason the conversion rate result is of a negative value. I have tried this for a number of values but all come back as failed with the `conversion rate` result always `-1`

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: Looks you forgot to add response?

Comment: We need to see your request and response, otherwise: close - cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

The resource have been broken, so it have not been able to give a valid response. It does not exist now. Solution is given [here](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Receiving-return-of-1-instead-of-conversion-rate-in-test-request/td-p/123230). And it states that you should try another resource for testing: [working resource](http://currencyconverter.kowabunga.net/converter.asmx?WSDL)

Comment: Can you point out the solution mentioned in the link so that it would be a lot more easier rather than just posting the link?